# How to activate mod_rewrite on MacOSX Lion

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I tried to activate the **mod_rewrite** module in the httpd.conf, but I do not succeed to make it work.
I'm running Lion, and my goal is to do URL rewriting in ~USER/Sites/mysite

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a conf file to the following dir

`/etc/apache2/users/yourname.conf`

```
<Directory "/Users/yourname/Sites/">
     Options Indexes MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from All
</Directory>
```